# sql trigger not firing with insert

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

```
DROP TABLE ENROLLMENT CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE SECTION CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE SECTION
(
 SectionID  CHAR(5),
 Course     VARCHAR2(7),
 Students   NUMBER(2,0) DEFAULT 0,

 CONSTRAINT PK_SECTION 
        PRIMARY KEY (SectionID)
);

CREATE TABLE ENROLLMENT
(
 SectionID  CHAR(5),
 StudentID  CHAR(7),

 CONSTRAINT PK_ENROLLMENT 
        PRIMARY KEY (SectionID, StudentID),

 CONSTRAINT FK_ENROLLMENT_SECTION 
        FOREIGN KEY (SectionID)
        REFERENCES SECTION (SectionID)
);

INSERT INTO SECTION (SectionID, Course) VALUES ( '12345', 'CSC 355' );
INSERT INTO SECTION (SectionID, Course) VALUES ( '22109', 'CSC 309' );
INSERT INTO SECTION (SectionID, Course) VALUES ( '99113', 'CSC 300' );
INSERT INTO SECTION (SectionID, Course) VALUES ( '99114', 'CSC 300' );
SELECT * FROM SECTION;
COMMIT;


CREATE TRIGGER AddStudent AFTER INSERT ON ENROLLMENT

BEGIN 

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DONE');
END;
```

All I am trying to see is if the trigger is fired and when I run a script like INSERT INTO enrollment VALUES('12345','1234567');

I have no output, just "1 row inserted" but I do not get "done" making me thing the trigger is not fired.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Triggers are **highly** vendor-specific - so we need to use if you're using Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server or something else entirely

Comment: oracle sql developer

Comment: You need to provide the table structure for SECTION and INSERT statements for ENROLLMENT. You have provided table structure and insert statements for two different tables. it is useless unless you provide all the details.

Comment: The insert statement was INSERT INTO enrollment VALUES ('12345', '1234567');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only observable effect of your insert trigger is this:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DONE');
```

This just puts a message into the debug buffer. To see the result, you need to enable DBMS Output.

You can do this in SQL Developer via the View menu, choose Dbms Output, and click the green "+" button. Then run your code and you should see the output, if any.

If you use SQL*Plus instead, you would run `SET SERVEROUT ON`.